# In a multi-monitor setup, all my windows get 'thrown' off the screen if I turn it off

Tags: multiple-monitors

I started having this really annoying problem recently. I have multiple monitors and when I turn one off, all the open windows that were on that monitor, get moved to the monitor that is still turned on. Previously, I could turn the monitor on and off and it would not change anything. So now I have to manually drag everything back onto the monitor every time I turn it on.

Comment: When the system detects a screen is no longer connected, it will reconfigure your displays, moving applications to the active screens. However, most screens and computers know the difference between a screen being disconnected and a screen being turned off. This raises the question: how are you turning the screen off?

Comment: I'm just pressing the 'off/on' button on the monitor. Like I said, in the past, when I did this everything remained in place. It just started doing this.

Comment: With the same screens as before? Does it do something different when you turn a different screen off? I would guess your screen might be going bad, but I'd update your graphics drivers and any system firmware before stating that as fact.

Comment: same screens but I did get a new computer. Everything is fully updated. Are you sure there isn't a setting somewhere in monitor display settings or something like that?

Comment: Is this a really difficult problem to fix? It's extremely annoying because I leave the computer on at all times, however I need to turn the monitors off in order to sleep. It takes a really long time to re-organize my workflow every single morning, considering I have multiple apps/windows open across three monitors.

Comment: Something in your system is not operating the way it ought. I have worked with computers for a long time and have never observed this behavior except when the screen is actually disconnected. If someone has observed this issue and sees this question they may give you an answer. However, I'm guessing either your screen or your new computer isn't functioning properly. You can address the software side by updating all drivers and your OS, and then you're left with hardware issues if it's still happening.

Comment: That's disheartening. Even stranger, I had _one_ screen where this was not an issue, a TV which I have connected to my PC via HDMI and which I use as my third monitor. The other two monitors are identical to each other. The TV, at least, never had this issue and continued to 'keep' everything as it should when I turn it back on. But starting yesterday, it too now 'loses' everything onto the other two monitors when I turn it off, if they are still turned on.